# Arrange label on top of the button (html, css)

Tags: html, css

How do I arrange two bootstrap buttons side by side and the label on top of the right-side button with the same width as the button?
this is what I have, so far:

```html
    <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <div class="input-group row">
        <input asp-for="SMSCode" class="form-control" placeholder="PIN" style="max-width:200px"/> 
                <p class="pull-right" style="max-width=200px;">This is some text that I would like to display on top of the red button.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" type="submit" style="margin:2em 0">Button 1</button>
                
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-danger pull-right" style="margin:2em 0 0 0" type="button" onclick='window.location="@Url.Action("Action", "COntroller")";'>Button 2</button>

    </div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your problem is not clear. Can you add a sketch?

Comment: Which button is the "red button"?

Comment: Sorry, "Button 2"

Comment: @SoftwareDveloper Need more details

Comment: OH, _above_ the button (vertically) — I interpreted _on top of_ as "stacked", like `z-index` stacking order. You would like to _left align_ the text with button 2, and appear just above the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this will help.  I wrapped your text and the button in a div and made some changes to the margin.  Is this what you are looking for?

https://jsfiddle.net/5spftze6/

```html
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<div class="input-group row">
    <input asp-for="SMSCode" class="form-control" placeholder="PIN" style="max-width:200px"/> 
            
</div>
<div class="row">
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" type="submit" style="margin:2em 0">Button 1</button>
    <div>
    
    <p style="max-width:200px;">This is some text that I would like to display on top of the red button.</p>  
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" type="button" onclick='window.location="@Url.Action("Action", "COntroller")";'>Button 2</button>
     </div>

</div>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I am looking for; just a question: how do I make the label multi-line with the same width as the button 2?

Comment: Thank you for your solution; It's been bugging me for an hour..

Comment: @SoftwareDveloper you need to change the `=` to a `:` in the `max-width=200px;` so that its `max-width:200px;` and it will scrunch it up.  I edited my answer to reflect this.